# Specific Template Friendship in C++

Tags: c++, templates, friend, access-control

I have a question for Specific Template Friendship in C++. 
in the book C++ Primer, the specific template friendship is written like this:

```
 template <class T> class Foo3;
 template <class T> void templ_fcn3(const T&);
 template <class Type> class Bar {
     // each instantiation of Bar grants access to the
     // version of Foo3 or templ_fcn3 instantiated with the same type
     friend class Foo3<Type>;
     friend void templ_fcn3<Type>(const Type&);
     // ...
 };
```

The special point is that there is

```
<Type>
```

after the class or function name in the **friend** statement.

However,in practice, if I write this:

```
template <class Type> class T_CheckPointer;
template <class T> T_CheckPointer<T> operator+(const T_CheckPointer<T> &, const size_t n);

template <typename Type>
class T_CheckPointer {

    // Specific Template Friendship
    friend T_CheckPointer<Type>
    operator+ <Type> (const T_CheckPointer<Type> &, const size_t n);

// other code...

}
```

There will be a error during instantiations for the template function.

And if I change

```
// Specific Template Friendship
friend T_CheckPointer<Type>
    operator+ <Type> (const T_CheckPointer<Type> &, const size_t n);
```

to

```
// Specific Template Friendship
friend T_CheckPointer<Type>
    operator+ <> (const T_CheckPointer<Type> &, const size_t n);
```

by deleting the word **type** after the function name, then all will be okay.

Anyone can tell me the reason?

---

For information, there is the **error message** when I call

```
int iarr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
T_CheckPointer<int> itcp(iarr, iarr+4);
```

error message:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h: In instantiation of ‘std::iterator_traits<int>’:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_iterator.h:96:   instantiated from ‘std::reverse_iterator<int>’
../Classes/T_CheckPointer.hpp:31:   instantiated from ‘T_CheckPointer<int>’
../PE16.cpp:520:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:127: error: ‘int’ is not a class, struct, or union type
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:128: error: ‘int’ is not a class, struct, or union type
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:129: error: ‘int’ is not a class, struct, or union type
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:130: error: ‘int’ is not a class, struct, or union type
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:131: error: ‘int’ is not a class, struct, or union type
```

Comment: @enobayram, thanks for your attention, I have put them in the article.

Comment: Could you provide a **minimal** example (that compiles on e.g. Ideone) that displays the problem? And did you try upgrading to gcc 4.7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a minimal example:

```
template<typename T> struct U { typedef typename T::X X; };
template<typename T> void foo(typename U<T>::X);

template<typename T> struct S;
template<typename T> void foo(S<T>);
template<typename T> struct S { friend void foo<T>(S<T>); };

template struct S<int>;
```

The reason the `friend` declaration fails is that by providing a full list of template arguments you are requesting the compiler specialize all available function templates and pick the one that best matches the signature.  Specialization of the first definition of `foo` results in specializing `U` with an argument that results in an ill-formed program.

If instead you omit the template argument, it will be deduced from the arguments.  As such template argument deduction is performed according to **14.8.2 [temp.deduct]**, and in particular 14.8.2p8 applies, which means that the substitution failure in the specialization of `U` is not an error (SFINAE).

This is a good reason to omit template arguments anywhere they can be deduced from context (e.g. here the function or operator parameter types).  Note that you still need to provide the `<>` brackets to ensure that the `operator +` is read as a *template-id* (**14.5.4 [temp.friend]**).

Comment: +1 This is a really great answer! Also note that the `<>` brackets are  to prevent non-template functions to be selected instead of template functions. See this old column by Herb Sutter http://www.drdobbs.com/befriending-templates/184403853

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot for your response! Your answer is very clear. @ecatmur